# LazyLoad without manually changing img structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, structure, lazy-loading

I've tried several LazyLoads but they all required changing the src tag or adding a new tag.

Is there a LazyLoader that doesn't require me to have to change the structure of the tag? I'm pulling content from WordPress functions so I would like to avoid altering the functions.

My temporary solution has been to use this

```
        $('img').each(function () {             
          $(this).attr('data-lazy', $(this).data('src'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no. And if you want to support Safari/iOS it is technically impossible.